# MONGODB - Find the difference of two arrays in a nested query

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, mongodb, nosql

i m trying to figure out how to do this kind of operation in a single query.

this is the example:

collection A

```
db.A.find({}, {_id: 0}) => result {tag: [dog, cat, horse]}
```

collection B

```
db.B.find({}, {_id: 0}) => result {tag: [dog, cat, bird]}
```

what i would like to know is how to get the different values from collection B respect the collection A and if any add to collection A.

actually i m using this method:

```
let a = db.A.find({}, {_id: 0}).toArray()[0].tag;
let b = db.B.find({}, {_id: 0}).toArray()[0].tag;

db.A.updateOne({},{$addToSet: {tag: {$each: b.filter(x => !a.includes(x))}}}) => result {tag: [dog, cat, horse, bird]}
```

that is not really nice but it works. do u know how to do in a single query?

thanks

Comment: Is there any logic to choose which document of A match which document of B (a join condition), or is there only one document per collection?

Comment: At the end, you combined the two arrays. It seems to me that you don't really need the *difference*, rather the *union* of two sets. If you are already using `$addToSet`, you don't really need to filter and can put `{ $each: b }`, as such, you don't actually need `db.A.find()`